# Changing column label Python plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python, streamlit

How to change column titles? First column title should say "4-Year" and 2nd column title "2-Year". I tried using label={} but kept getting an error.

```
df = pd.read_csv('college_data.csv')
    df1 = df[df.years > 2]
    df2 = df[df.years < 3]

    #CUNY College Table
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
        header=dict(values=list(df1[['college_name', 'college_name']]),
                    fill_color='paleturquoise',
                    font_color='gray',
                    align='left',
                    height = 50,
                    font=dict(size=26),
                    ),
        cells=dict(values=[df1.college_name, df2.college_name],
                height = 50,
                fill_color='lavender',
                align='left',
                font=dict(size=20),
                ))
    ])
    fig.update_layout(title = "CUNY Colleges",
                        width = 900,
                        height = 1320,
                        font_family='Palanquin',
                        font=dict(size=30),
                        showlegend = False)

    st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

[image: Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
values=list(df1[['college_name', 'college_name']]),
```

to

```
values=["4-year", "2-year"],
```

e.g.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
        header=dict(values=["4-year", "2-year"],
        ...
```

Calling `list` on a pandas `DataFrame` returns a list of the *column names* of that dataframe, so `list(df1[['college_name', 'college_name']])` is essentially identical to `['college_name', 'college_name']`.